# I'm not understanding what starvation means as this author explains it

Tags: multithreading

In [objc.io Issue 2](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/concurrency-apis-and-pitfalls.html) the author talks about the issue of Starvation with reading and writing:

> Just when you thought that there are enough problems to think of, a new one comes around the corner. Locking shared resources can result in the readers-writers problem. In many cases, it would be wasteful to restrict reading access to a resource to one access at a time. Therefore, taking a reading lock is allowed as long as there is no writing lock on the resource. In this situation, a thread that is waiting to acquire a write lock can be starved by more read locks occurring in the meantime.

I assume a reading lock is only allowing the thing that locked it access to read the value, while all others are not able to access it? I understand that you could only read lock if there's no write lock (as the value might be changing), but in the way it uses therefore it seems to imply that "read locks are only allowed if there's no write locks" is used as a means of efficiency/not being wasteful. What does taking a reading lock have to do with being wasteful?

Also, could anyone explain what the last sentence means? I don't understand what impact the read locks would have, or what the read locks would even be on.

Comment: The English of the quote is a bit less than clear.  "In this situation..." probably should be changed to "This (referring to the prior sentence) prevents the situation where...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what it means is that a read lock allows other items to read the data at the same time.
So imagine the following scenario.

A takes a read lock and starts reading.
Then X comes along and tries to take a write lock, but can't, because it's already locked.
Meanwhile, before A finishes reading, B comes along and takes a read lock. This is allowed because read locks can be concurrent.
Then, A finishes, but X still can't write, because it's locked by B.
Then, before B finishes, C comes along and takes out a read lock. Etc.

Comment: So what does a read lock do that's special? Without a read lock multiple objects aren't able to read an object at the same time? At all? Or is it just special in that it prevents a write lock? Does it prevent all writing?

Comment: Yeah, a read lock prevents writing, but allows other readers to also read. In general that's good (you don't want someone writing on the page you're reading, but you don't care if someone is reading over your shoulder), but if there is a line of 5000 people all trying to read the same thing, and someone else really wants to change something, they can get locked out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when you have "shared read" and "exclusive write" locks.  Multiple "shared read" locks can be applied to the entity at the same time, and they will prevent any "exclusive write" lock from gaining access.

"Starvation" occurs when new "shared read" locks keep arriving, before all existing ones are released.  This can hold off an "exclusive write" lock indefinitely.

There are several strategies for handling this, such as preventing any new "shared read" lock from being applied if there is an "exclusive write" lock waiting.

Answer (score 0):

1) If only a single read lock were allowed on a shared resource, it would be "wasteful" because any threads which only wanted to read the shared resource would have to queue up and read the resource one at a time.

2) A read lock will not prevent other threads from taking out a read lock, but would prevent other threads from taking write locks.

3) As you can't write lock a shared resource which has one or more read locks on it, the starvation thing would occur if several threads where continually requesting read locks (imagine them in an overlapping fashion); the thread which wanted the write lock would never be able to take it as there would always be a read lock.